# Android Studio - Remove Module - IncorrectOperationException: Must not change document outside command or undo-transparent action

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I'm trying to remove/delete a module I've in my project.

I go to "Module Settings" and then I select my module and press the "-" (minus) button. It ask's me if I really want to delete it and I do press "yes". Then this Exception is genereated:

```
12:53:05 ExtensionException: org.intellij.lang.batch.runner.BatchRunConfigurationProducer: org.intellij.lang.batch.runner.BatchRunConfigurationProducer
12:53:10 IncorrectOperationException: Must not change document outside command or undo-transparent action. See com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction or com.intellij.openapi.command.CommandProcessor: Must not change document outside command or undo-transparent action. See com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction or com.intellij.openapi.command.CommandProcessor
```

If I got back to module settings my module is not there anymore but it is still in the project tree. I re-start android studio and go back to module settings and my module is back there again.

Anyone has this problem? How can I fix this?

Using android studio 0.5.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a bug; I haven't tested it to see if it will be fixed in 0.5.2, but there are exceptions of this sort all over the place that are really annoying at the moment.

As a workaround, remove the reference to your module in your **settings.gradle** file and click the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button. Your module files will still be on disk and you will be able to see them from the Project view in the IDE, but they won't be linked into the code any more, and you can delete the files if you wish.

UPDATE

It's bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67220 and will be fixed in the 0.5.2 or 0.5.3 release.

Comment: 0.6.1 does indeed now have the remove button, but it seems to be regenerating the module every time, even if I try deleting from disk or removing from build file.

Answer (score 14):

Right click the project > Open Module Settings

[image]

select the module you want to remove (In my case its app2)

then click the "-" (Delete) button on the top.

[image]

That's it, your module is removed from project now. To remove the folder, just delete it.

Comment: Android is getting complex day by day.. rather than writing logic for app, we are stuck with stupid tools. this really sucks !

Comment: it comes again automatically if i delete as you suggest... any other solution?

Comment: Did you try deleting the folder from filesystem also? After removing it from project?